# Flutter - Sliver Layout horizontal scroll inside Sliver List

Tags: mobile, layout, dart, flutter

I try to make horizontal scrollable list inside **Sliver List (CustomScrollview - SliverList)**

This is my Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
    body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
        DetailAppBar(),
        SliverPadding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          sliver: SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
              [
                Card(child: Text('data'),),
                Card(child: Text('data'),),
                Card(child: Text('data'),),
                Card(child: Text('data'),),

                // Scrollable horizontal widget here
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    bottomNavigationBar: NavigationButton());


 }

}
```

Can you give me example or solution to this case? i really need some help.

Comment: change the scrollDirection to horizontal . i.e `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
`

Comment: no, i mean just the widget in my "// Scrollable horizontal widget here". but your solutions make all the widget from top to bottom horizontally scroll

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use a `ListView` inside of a `SliverToBoxAdapter`.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverPadding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            sliver: SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                [
                  Card(
                    child: Text('data'),
                  ),
                  Card(
                    child: Text('data'),
                  ),
                  Card(
                    child: Text('data'),
                  ),
                  Card(
                    child: Text('data'),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Container(
              height: 100.0,
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: 10,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Container(
                    width: 100.0,
                    child: Card(
                      child: Text('data'),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: How to make ListView height responsive without specify height for Container?

Comment: you can't due to the fact how listviews work. They try to take as much space as possible and can't get a size from another listview. What you could do is calculate the height of your items and set the height of the listview accordingly

Comment: @ChristianX: How would you calculate height of items ? I mean do you mean hardcoding them ? or is there a way to get widgets height ?

Answer (score 2):

the other solution doesn't work for me as it gives error when I use a `ListView`

here is a class I wrote called `HorizontalSliverList` which does the job nice and easy

**here is the class you need to copy:**

```dart
class HorizontalSliverList extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Widget> children;
  final EdgeInsets listPadding;
  final Widget divider;

  const HorizontalSliverList({
    Key key,
    @required this.children,
    this.listPadding = const EdgeInsets.all(8),
    this.divider,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SliverToBoxAdapter(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Padding(
          padding: listPadding,
          child: Row(children: [
            for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) ...[
              children[i],
              if (i != children.length - 1) addDivider(),
            ],
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget addDivider() => divider ?? Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8));
}
```

Comment: As items in list gets more, you will have performance issue. It maybe okay to use let's say up to 5 items.