# How to achieve horizontal grid scroll with sliver

Tags: flutter, gridview, scroll, flutter-sliver, sliver-grid

How to get horizontal grid view similar to this [example](https://www.kindacode.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/Flutter-Horizontal-GridView.mp4) using `sliver:[]`. I've tries using he example given [here](https://www.kindacode.com/article/how-to-implement-a-horizontal-gridview-in-flutter/) but it is using mutiple container inside children to get the desired result. also tries giving it to list.generate but that dosen't seems to work or I don't really know how to use it.

Note: I have other multiple scroll list too inside [ ]

Here is what what I have working but it comes out as List:

```
  body: CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      SliverPadding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
        sliver: SliverGrid(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            childAspectRatio: 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 16,
            mainAxisSpacing: 16,
            crossAxisCount: 2,
          ),
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (BuildContext context, int i) {
              return InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: ClipRRect(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 200,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image:
                              CachedNetworkImageProvider('categoryImage'),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          onError: (exception, stackTrace) =>
                              LoadingImage(),
                        ),
                        gradient: const LinearGradient(
                          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                          colors: [
                            Color(0x1FFFFFFF),
                            Color(0x463B3B3B),
                          ],
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.grey.shade900,
                              offset: const Offset(1, 1),
                              spreadRadius: 1,
                              blurRadius: 50,
                              blurStyle: BlurStyle.outer),
                        ]),
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Text(
                        "title",
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1!,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            childCount: count.length,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  )
```

Comment: This should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/52766231/17104517

Comment: You can use this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52738034/flutter-sliver-layout-horizontal-scroll-inside-sliver-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52738034/flutter-sliver-layout-horizontal-scroll-inside-sliver-list) And replace ListView with GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Add `scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,` inside [`CustomScrollView`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html), Just Change My images with your hope its help to you

Full Widget:

```
CustomScrollView(
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    slivers: [
      SliverPadding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
        sliver: SliverGrid(
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            childAspectRatio: 2,
            crossAxisSpacing: 16,
            mainAxisSpacing: 16,
            crossAxisCount: 2,
          ),
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (BuildContext context, int i) {
              return InkWell(
                onTap: () {},
                child: ClipRRect(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 200,
                    width: double.infinity,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: NetworkImage(
                              'https://storage.googleapis.com/cms-storage-bucket/a9d6ce81aee44ae017ee.png'),
                        ),
                        gradient: const LinearGradient(
                          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                          colors: [
                            Color(0x1FFFFFFF),
                            Color(0x463B3B3B),
                          ],
                        ),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.grey.shade900,
                              offset: const Offset(1, 1),
                              spreadRadius: 1,
                              blurRadius: 50,
                              blurStyle: BlurStyle.outer),
                        ]),
                    child: Container(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                      height: 100,
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                      width: double.infinity,
                      child: Text(
                        "title",
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1!,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            },
            childCount: 20,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Result Image-> [image]

Comment: although I have other SliverToBoxAdapter() in CustomScrollView(), applying Axis.horizontal would apply to all other list too. So I created another class with CustomScrollView() and there aded Axis.horizontal. did worked.

Comment: @Digambernegi, Cant understood your problem is resolved?

Comment: ultimatily resolved.

Comment: Ok if helpful to you mark my answer